# How to sort the sequence of checkbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox

I have two checkboxes. If I check cb1 first and cb2 next, the ListBox should display the data of the checkboxes in order of checked sequence.

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If cb1.Checked = True And cb2.Checked = False Then
      ListBox1.Items.Add(cb1.Text)
      If cb1.Checked = True And cb2.Checked = True Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(cb1.Text)
      End If
    ElseIf cb2.Checked = True And cb1.Checked = False Then
      ListBox1.Items.Add(cb2.Text)
      If cb2.Checked = True And cb1.Checked = True Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(cb1.Text)
      End If
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

If only one checkbox is checked it displays the data, but if both are checked there's no data displayed in the list box.

[image]

Comment: `"vb.net code needed"` - Have *you* written any code yet?  At all?  What attempt have you made to solve your problem and where are you stuck?  In what way is your code not doing what you expect?  What is that code and where does the problem occur?  We can *help you*, but we won't *do your work for you*.

Comment: I used if cb1.checked=true AND cb2.checked=false then listbox.items.add(cb1.text)

Comment: Edit your question, show your code there, show output and then tell what is expected output and what are you getting.

Comment: And what is the problem?  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here.  Whatever other code you have, we don't know about it.  Whatever behavior you're seeing, we're not seeing it.  Don't just point at your monitor and say "it isn't working".  *Explain the problem*.  In most cases, the effort made to understand the problem reveals the solution.

Comment: `"if only one checkbox is checked it displays the data but if both checked there's no data displayed in the list box"` - Because your logic doesn't cover that scenario.  Take a look at your `If` and `ElseIf` conditions.  They only account for when *one* check box is checked, but not *both*.  If you want to maintain this structure, you'd have to add another `ElseIf` for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is not clear enough for me to be sure of what you want exactly but here is the solution to the question I interpreted:

Your code for checking if both were true was nested within if statements which wouldn't run if they were both true.
Also, dont put an end if at the end of an elseif if you have more criteria to come.

Fixed code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)         Handles Button1.Click
    If cb1.Checked = True AND cb2.Checked = False Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(cb1.Text)
    ElseIf cb1.Checked = True AND cb2.Checked = True Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(cb1.Text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(cb2.Text)
    End if

    If cb2.Checked = True And cb1.Checked = False Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(cb2.Text)
    ElseIf cb2.Checked = True And cb1.Checked = True Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(cb2.Text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(cb1.Text)
    End If

End Sub
```

You would probably have better luck if you made an event happen automatically after each one is checked. This code will only run once, so if you have only one checked and the code runs, even if the other one is then checked, the code won't run again unless you have it in some sort of loop (until loop could work).